# Xamarin System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a mobile project with Xamarin Forms and I have this error in particulary case but, it's impossible to use the debuger to fix it.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'
```

Little bit of context:
I am in a TabPage ( from DevExpress ) and when I navigate through the tab, this error occurs sometimes.

So I use a little bit of Stream object in my code, but honestly I don't know where could be the error.

So here is my code with Stream object

```cs
public async Task<bool> TakePhotoAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
                await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
                Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: {PhotoPath}");
                return true;
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Device not supported");
                return false;
            }
            catch (PermissionException pEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Permission non accordée");
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
        {
            // canceled
            string path = "";
            if (photo == null)
            {
                this.PhotoPath = null;
                return;
            }
            // save the file into local storage
            using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
                DependencyService.Get<IDeviceDependency>().SaveImage(stream, "photo", $"{bon.DOSSIER.DODOS}_BT_{bon.CLE_DOSPRESTA_BON}_{NbPhoto++}.png", ref path);
            this.PhotoPath = path;
        }
```

```cs
public class MyDependencyService: IDeviceDependency
    {
        public bool SaveImage(Stream image, string directory, string name, ref string PhotoPath)
        {
            string path = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(directory).AbsolutePath;

            if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            if (image != null && image.CanWrite)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                image.CopyTo(ms);

                path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, name);
                PhotoPath = path;
                File.WriteAllBytes(path, ms.ToArray());
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        public bool SaveImage(Stream image, string directory, string name)
        {
            string value = "";
            return this.SaveImage(image, directory, name, ref value);
        }

        public FileStream ShowImage(string directory, string name)
        {
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(directory).AbsolutePath, name);
            FileStream stream = null;

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                try
                {
                    stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
                }
                catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
            }

            return stream;
        }

        public bool DeleteFile(string directory, string name)
        {
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(directory).AbsolutePath, name);
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public Stream ResizeImageAndroid(byte[] imageData, double width, double height)
        {
            if ( imageData.Length > 0 )
            {
                // Load the bitmap
                Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
                Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(originalImage, (int)width, (int)height, false);

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                resizedImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, ms);
                return new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
            }
            return null;
        }

        public string GetExternalXMLPath(string name)
        {
            return System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("xml").AbsolutePath, name);
        }
```

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            this.Model.ExecuteRefreshCommand();
            FileStream stream = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceDependency>().ShowImage("signature", "76");
            Stream streamImg;

            double rapport = this.ImgSignature.HeightRequest/Signature.HAUTEUR_SIGNATURE;

            if (stream != null && stream.CanWrite)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                stream.CopyTo(ms);
                streamImg = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceDependency>().ResizeImageAndroid(ms.ToArray(), rapport*(App.Current.MainPage.Width - 30),
                                                                                                        rapport*Signature.HAUTEUR_SIGNATURE);

                if (streamImg != null && streamImg.CanRead)this.ImgSignature.Icon = ImageSource.FromStream(() => streamImg);
            }

            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

**UPDATE**
I also find the call stack error for [External Code] look like this

```
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal  C#
0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/Debugger.cs:125,4   C#
0x33 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.84 C#
0xD in System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureNotClosed at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs:121,17  C#
0x4F in System.IO.MemoryStream.Read at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs:369,13    C#
0x9 in Android.Runtime.InputStreamAdapter.Read at /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/InputStreamAdapter.cs:38,4 C#
0x23 in Java.IO.InputStream.n_Read_arrayBII at /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-30/mcw/Java.IO.InputStream.cs:251,4 C#
0x23 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.84 C#
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_static_object_method_a    C#
0x59 in Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod    C#
0x1A in Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod C#
0x2F in Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream at /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-30/mcw/Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.cs:825,5  C#
0x6 in Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory. at /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-30/mcw/Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.cs:835,58  C#
0x11 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Android.Graphics.Bitmap>.InnerInvoke at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534,17    C#
0x1 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319,17   C#
0x6 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2463,13  C#
0x73 in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968,17   C#
0x4 in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910,13    C#
0x38 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/corert/Task.cs:72,6    C#
0x50 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2385,17 C#
0x2 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2334,13  C#
0x75 in System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:899,29 C#
0x0 in System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:1261,13  C#
```

Comment: VS menu Debugger / Windows / Exception Settings. Checkbox by  Common Language Runtime Exceptions, so all of them are on. Then it should pause at line exception happens on.

Comment: the exception stack trace should show you the source of the error.  You should also wrap your stream operations in a try/catch to capture the failure

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve; I try this to see the error, but nothing change except that previously the exception was not managed by the user and now I only have the exception.
@Jason I try to put some try catch but nothing change too. Also, when the error occurs I have in call stack "[External Code]" who appears for the name and nothing for the language

**Update** I test on my personal phone and it's working, so the question Is: "Why it didn't work on my phone and not on the "work" phone ?"
Personal => Android 11
Work     => Android 9

Comment: FWIW: **1)** `MemoryStream.EnsureNotClosed` error: The way you did it in question, the stream `streamImg` might already be closed by the time it is used. Or it might not - not reliable, but it happened to work on one device. **2)** Its not necessary to **explicitly resize** an Android image in X-Forms. Simply use `WidthRequest` and/or `HeightRequest` on xaml button or image.

Answer (score 0):

I find an issue,
According to the [External error], the error occurs from the Bitmap.Decode function.
So I just delete this part of code and replace my Simplebutton with Icon by an ImageIcon and the resize was automatic so don't need of Bitmap.

Regards for your help!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).